# I am unable to install any modules of Python 3.7 in Windows 7 by using pip installer

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, python, visual-studio-2015

Using pip:

> C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pip install pyaudio

Output:

```
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyaudio ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\pytho
n37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DELL\\
AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-2wt7vi91\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(comp
ile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\tm
pos8y8pmgpip-wheel- --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /
Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-3
2\include -Ic:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-IC
:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Fil
es (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Wi
ndows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\includ
e\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudi
omodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'port
audio.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN
\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

---

```
  Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
Complete output from command c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\pyt
hon37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\DELL
\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-2wt7vi91\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokeniz
e, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(co
mpile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Tem
p\pip-04qjfess-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --c
ompile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.7
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.7
creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo
 /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37
-32\include -Ic:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include "-
IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program F
iles (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\
Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\incl
ude\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc/_portau
diomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
_portaudiomodule.c
src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'po
rtaudio.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B
IN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: no one is helping me or responding me just demoting my questions see there -3 rating on this question without any discussion although it is detailed question

Comment: Crucial info is missing. What do you want to achieve? What were your steps prior to that? What command did you run? Are you running it from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: yaa the command was 'pip install pyaudio'

Comment: now i edited my question and copy pasted everything in question so now plzzz help me @gronostaj

Comment: @RahulGupta I have posted an (extremely) short answer. Basically, you should move back to the Python 3.6.x line (currently) if you want to ensure that your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that this will be the answer you are looking for, but my suggestion would be to move back to Python 3.6.x if you wish to use pip and the currently available wheels.

As of February 2018, [Python 3.7 is a beta preview](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370b1/), not a full release. This means that A) there will be bugs, technical/implementation issues and other limitations and B) third-party projects like [pyaudio](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAudio) likely haven't produced compatible wheels for Python 3.7 yet:

[image: pyaudio_wheels]

Comment: yes it helped me installing pyaudio and other packages in python 3.6 very easily but i still cant install 1 package that is 'speech_recognition'             and why there is -5 rating on my question although ihad asked valid question with all the details @Anaksunaman

Comment: @RahulGupta By `speech_recognition` I assume you mean [Uberi/speech_recognition on GitHub](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition) which is under [SpeechRecognition on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/). If so, you should try omitting the underscore and capitalizing the first letter of each word i.e. `pip install SpeechRecognition`.

Comment: @RahulGupta Regarding the -5 on the question, don't take it personally. Its somewhat common for people who have never posted here to have their first questions downvoted for technical reasons. You should read [How Do I Ask Ask A Good Question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask?).

Comment: @RahulGupta But since you want specifics, perhaps here are some things to consider.. First, the formatting was very difficult to read. You needed to break up your input and output and use some of the special formatting SuperUser provides (such as four leading spaces for "code" blocks). Second, regarding details, you gave too few. While it's true there were just barely enough to assist you superficially, things that seem inconsequential often matter.

Comment: @RahulGupta For instance, if you had listed the packages you were having difficulty with (or even a link to a tutorial, if you were following one), perhaps I could have already assisted with the `speech_recognition` issue. Third, you presented no troubleshooting or research. It doesn't help anyone if we're giving you the same solutions you've already tried. These things saves us time, you time, and makes the questions better for others who come across your post on Google.

Comment: that 'pip install SpeechRecognition' help me , it ran successfully and also when i checked by using 'help('modules')' then there was 'speech_recognition' module installed ,but i have a question. that if i have used 'pip install SpeechRecognition' then how did 'speech_recognition' module got installed? @Anaksunaman

Comment: @RahulGupta `speech_recognition` was installed as a part of `SpeechRecognition`. Module names (e.g. `SpeechRecognition`) do not always reflect the names of the items you import into your program in Python to make them function (e.g. `speech_recognition`). More specifically, `speech_recogintion` is apparently a class which is used to create specific objects/instances to handle speech recognition functions.

Comment: okkk thnx alot @Anaksunaman your every response helped me alot

Comment: @RahulGupta Glad to help. =)